# Android acvitiy scale, fade exit animation not working

Tags: android, xml, animation

So I'm trying to transition from one activity with:

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.scale_fade_in, R.anim.scale_fade_out);

scale_fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="500">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.85" android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.85" android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"/>
</set>
```

scale_fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="500">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="1.5"
        android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.5"
        android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0"/>
</set>
```

The problem is that the scale_fade_out animation isn't happening. The first activity sits there while the second activity scales in (as it should). What I'm trying to achieve is the first activity to scale up a little bit AND fade out while the second activity does the same except fading in.

Comment: Try adding `android:shareInterpolator="true"` to your fade out set

Comment: Still having the same issue. scale_fade_out is simply not happening

Comment: You will have to use the Scale-fade-out animation programmatically on the existing activity that is exiting. See overridePendingTransition - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int).